# "SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet" With liquibase and quarkus

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase, quarkus

I'm working on a quarkus project, which uses liquibase as a db.

This is my hibernate class:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "votingResult")
public class VotingResultEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "voting-result_id_seq",
            sequenceName = "voting-result_id_seq",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "voting-result_id_seq"
    )
    @Column(name = "voting-result_id")
    private Long votingResultId;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "end-date")
    private long endDate;

}
```

This is my liquibase table definition:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext
    https://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
    https://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.4.xsd">

    <changeSet author="GoldNova" id="32-create-voting-result-table">

        <createTable tableName="votingResult">
            <column name="voting-result_id" type="bigint">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" primaryKeyName="voting-result_id_pk"/>
            </column>
            <column name="title" type="varchar(255)"/>
            <column name="end-date" type="bigint"/>
        </createTable>

        <createSequence sequenceName="voting-result_id_seq"
                        dataType="bigint"
                        incrementBy="1"
                        startValue="100"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

the changelog xml:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
    https://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.4.xsd">

    <include file="17-create-sample-table.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="32-create-voting-result-table.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Now, if I execute the service I get the following errors:

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
> ResultSet

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "votingresult" does not exist

It is not a service related error, that is for sure. But what could be the problem?
I've checked the DB definition and the hibernate annotations and they seem fine to me. Also the other error does not make sense because the table obviously does exist in the definition...

What could be the problem?

EDIT: I''ve tried renaming my table to `voting-result` but when I do that I get an error saying `sql error near -`

Comment: is `-` a valid PGSQL identifier char? If not, I'll start quoting all column names with `` (as describerd in Hibernate doc).
Also, edit OP and add full stacktrace because is not clear if the problem is generated by Liquibase or your application code.